# rust windows: Setting file permissions to owner-only read/write

Tags: windows, file, rust

I got the following rust code:

```rust
fn create_pgpass_file(pgpass_file: PathBuf) -> Result<File, errors::ToolsError> {
    let mut open_options = OpenOptions::new();
    open_options.write(true).create(true);

    set_permissions(&mut open_options);

    open_options
        .open(pgpass_file)
        .map_err(errors::ToolsError::FailedToCreatePgpassFile)
}

#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
fn set_permissions(open_options: &mut OpenOptions) {
    open_options.mode(0o600);
}
```

Now I want to support windows also, how do I change the file permissions for windows to allow read/write to the owner only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, this isn't well supported at the moment. The hierarchy of choices for these kinds of operations are:

1. Use Standard Library
2. Use a well-established general purpose crate with the OS support you need
3. Use a well-established OS specific crate
4. Use a small crate after verification that you trust
5. Call into the underling C API the OS makes available

If you're reading permissions, the decently popular [faccess](https://crates.io/crates/faccess) has Windows support.

For writing, I'm not aware of any. If you're not finding one either the underlying C APIs in Windows to consider are:

- Use the full Windows security settings concepts, dealing with some are filesystem specific, and hopefully the [generic crate](https://docs.rs/windows-permissions/latest/windows_permissions/) is sufficient
- [_chmod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/chmod-wchmod?view=msvc-170) (which seeks to mirror the chmod experience in Linux)

Going with chmod is the more straightforward path, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to be supported in the [winapi crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi) which is what makes the system calls easier in the other crates I've mentioned. For instance this snippet from faccess:

```rust
let err = unsafe {
                GetNamedSecurityInfoW(
                    pathw.as_ptr(),
                    SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                    OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                        | GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                        | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION
                        | LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                    &mut owner,
                    &mut group,
                    &mut dacl,
                    std::ptr::null_mut(),
                    &mut sd,
                )
            };
```

Corresponds nicely to Microsoft's docs for the C function.

If you go with chmod consider:

- Modifying winapi crate
- Just write the one off FFI code yourself, similar to what winapi crate does

Either way, you end up with a wrapper function that's easier to work with, as if you're just using the C interface directly the way the docs describe. This isn't a direct answer as much as it is a roadmap to a solution. If no one else ends up sharing a better or pre-implemented and do end up implementing it, consider contributing back to winapi.

I do feel doubt it hasn't been done yet, but neither of us found it and rust on Windows isn't nearly as common, so maybe it is the case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It's a bit weird as rust advocated to be used as a CLI tool, so I thought it will be used to run on windows machines.
[winapi](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs) looks very inactive, so the only option is to fork which doesn't looks like a good idea.

Comment: I'm hoping that a better answer comes along at some point, or someone has time to implement one. When I saw your question, I thought wait really that's not supported? And sure enough, doesn't look like a good option exists. I suspect the need to do this will come up at my work at some point, so maybe we can get someone to make a contribution.

Comment: @OmerShtivi *"winapi looks very inactive"* - you should use the [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate since it is maintained by Microsoft. Though it is still just the bare OS calls so you'll have to figure out elsewhere what calls to make and what to call them with. I'm not familiar with access control on Windows, but hopefully [this will help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptors).